# reset wordpress default theme (TwentyThirteen) style for buttons

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I develop a plugin that for wordpress and has a lot of content in it (forms lists etc.).

I know this is asked several times but not in **wordpress contects**.

The default theme for TwentyThirteen puts some ugly styles on all button:

```
button, 
input[type="submit"], 
input[type="button"], 
input[type="reset"]{
    background: #e05d22;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e05d22 0%, #d94412 100%);
    border-bottom: 3px solid #b93207;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 11px 24px 10px;
}
```

and several more **diferent** definitions for `:focus`, `:active`, `:hover`.

This is not a big issue if you have heavy staled page with custom buttons look...
but in my case I rely use **jquery**  and **twitter-bootstrap** and there styles get completely messedup (red borders on hover, random paddings and so on).

And overriding the styles for close button on DatePicker for example just to make it look NORMAL... is not fun.

This seems as a general issue to me but I m new to wordpress themes and plugins...
so what is good solution for clearing /normalizing this particular styles ?

(Just reset CSS will remove most of the default looks)

Answer (score 0):

try `!important` as it has the highest priority other than `inline style`.

Comment: !important will fixate (lets say the background) to a specific color.. and all hover effect or styles from libraries will stop working.

Comment: have you tried adding the `!important` rule using jquery? and what possible ways have u tried applying the css too.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you plan to use twentythirteen, but you need to change the style for a few elements. This can be easily done with a child theme. It is very easy to do a child theme, look it up on google or there are plenty of tutorials on youtube. Here is one example of creating a child theme http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/wordpress-child-theme-tutorial and here is a youtube tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvzlw8D6pvk 
In your theme style.css you only have to redefine the styles that cause problem. And they will automatically override twentythirteen, leaving the rest unchanged.

Comment: No, my work is on the plugin only and not on the WP configs. So distributing it with a child theme makes no sense.

Comment: Then I think you have a more fundamental problem since your plugin obviously does not work with any theme. In a good designed plugin you should let the theme decided on the styles. Now you could hook into wordpress page loading to add/override styles. Look up "WP_Styles" in the wordpress documentation. But doing this will probably cause other "surprises" in the future since theme developers don't expect a plugin to interfere with their styling. There will definitely be themes out there that does not work with your plugin.